# How to specify a division for cytoscape.js in html?

Tags: html, css, cytoscape.js

I am trying to use cytoscape.min.js in one of my HTML page for showing interactions. Looking into some examples, I am able to develop a page for the same.

However, I am not able to specify this into a particular division, The "#cy" division is not in the space of proper division. In more detail, when I will develop a page with multiple contents, I want to restrict the interaction view (using cytoscpae) into a particular division in HTML. I guess something to modify in the style of "#cy" division, but not able to do so.

I would like to get any suggestion/help regarding this.

Thanks in advance,

Santosh

My current HTML page is like following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cytoscape example</title>
    <script src='cytoscape.min.js'></script>
</head>
<style>
    #cy {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div>
<h1> Interactions </h1>
<h1> Test data </h1>
</div>
<div id="cy"></div>
<script>
      var cy = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cy'),
elements: [
  // nodes
  { data: { id: 'a', type: "met" } },
  { data: { id: 'b', type: "met" } },
  { data: { id: 'c', type: "prot" } },
  { data: { id: 'd', type: "prot" } },
  { data: { id: 'e', type: "prot" } },
  { data: { id: 'f', type: "prot" } },
  // edges
  {
    data: {
      id: 'ab',
      source: 'a',
      target: 'b'
    }
  },
  {
     data: {
      id: 'ae',
      source: 'a',
      target: 'e'
    }
  }, 
  {
    data: {
      id: 'cd',
      source: 'c',
      target: 'd'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'ef',
      source: 'e',
      target: 'f'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'ac',
      source: 'a',
      target: 'c'
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: 'be',
      source: 'b',
      target: 'e'
    }
  }
], 
        style: [
  {
    selector: 'node[type="prot"]',
    style: {
      'shape': 'circle',
      'background-color': 'red',
      label: 'data(id)'
    }
  },
  {
    selector: 'node[type="met"]',
    style: {
      'shape': 'square',
      'background-color': 'blue',
      label: 'data(id)'
    }
  }]
      });
      cy.layout({
    name: 'circle',
    animate: true
}).run();
</script>
</body>
</html>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the current code looks fine for me and does the job.

If you want to make the `div` smaller, you can do like this:

```css
#cy {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I suggest you add the border while in development, just to know where the `div` is. Without the border, the `div` still works fine, but it might be difficult to tell where it is on the page and click it.